# Character Encoding Issue - Characters Being Replaced with Random Characters after Saving in Textarea

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, non-ascii-characters, htmlspecialchars

I'm working with a third-party company and I'm trying/hoping to determine the cause of a character encoding issue before I bring it up with them.

This company has a custom drag and drop editor for designing websites on their platform. Within the editor they have a `Raw HTML` widget that I can drag in and add my own content too. The problem is that when I copy HTML from someones old website, using the inspector tool, and paste it into this widget of theirs, all of the apostrophe's & double quotes get replaced with 'jibberish'. I also have the same issue when I try pasting the content into notepad, notepad++, sublime editors and then pasting it into their `Raw HTML` editor.

Here's a recording of the issue and a few examples:
https://streamable.com/phwn2

> Here are the known characters that get replaced and what they get replaced
>
> - ’ turns into â™
> - “ turns into âœ
> - ” turns into â
> - + turns into (a space)
> - Å turns into Ã…
> - " stays as "
> - ' stays as '

Does anyone see a pattern with these characters or know what could be the cause of these characters being replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website probably has UTF-8 encoding, and the company's editor might be using something like Windows-1252 encoding. In your first example, the right single quote has UTF-8 encoding e2 80 99. When each of those bytes is read by a program using Windows-1252, you get "small latin letter a with circumflex" (e2), [undefined] 80 and "trademark" (99). I haven't checked the other transformations. If this is the problem, then you could do a workaround by first converting the copied characters to the destination encoding with iconv, before pasting into the company's editor.

Comment: You are spot on. These changes are exactly the same when testing a conversion from utf-8 to windows-125(0,2,6,7,8, etc.) here http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx

Thank you so much! You have no idea how much headache you just saved me =D

Comment: What would be the fix if they can't change the encoding; which I assume is set in their database or editor? I guess the only thing they can do is a regex query/search & replace for non-windows-1252 chars?

Comment: @BlakeBell. If they can't change the encoding in their application, there's nothing they can do. The "UTF-8 bytes" will continue to be read as "Windows-1252" bytes. Regex searches for *characters* won't work. The only workaround is to convert UTF-8 text to Windows-1252 text before pasting into the application. Check out http://kunststube.net/encoding/